# Prove that if $xHy$ & $pHq$ left and right double cosets of $H$ in $G$, then either $xHy = pHq$ or $xHy \cap pHq = \emptyset$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and $H$ be a subgroup of $G.$ A left and right double coset of $H$ in $G$ is a set of the form $xHy$ where $x,y \in G.$ Prove that if $xHy$ & $pHq$ left and right double cosets of $H$ in $G$, then either $xHy = pHq$ or $xHy \cap pHq = \emptyset$.

Comment: Any insights you have for this problem?

Comment: Are these really double cosets?

Answer (score 0):

A double coset is a set $HxH=\{h_1xh_2:h_1,h_2\in H\}$ (or more generally a set $H_1xH_2$).

These are not double cosets. Consider $eHe$ and $xHx^{-1}$. These
contain the identity $e$, so intersect non-trivially, but in general
$eHe=H\ne xHx^{-1}$.

However, genuine double cosets $HxH$ and $HyH$ are either disjoint or equal.